# Why is IronPython code failing?

Tags: ironpython

I am working through IronPython in Action.

The following code fails at the line that reads **label=Label()**
The error returned is NameError: name 'Label' is not defined

This is exactly as in the book.  And I don't know why it can't resolve the Label class...especially since it resolves the Form class with no problems.  Any ideas?

Seth

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')


from System.Windows.Forms import Application,Form
form=Form()
form.Text='Hello World'
label=Label()
label.Text='Wassup'
form.Controls.Add(label)

Application.Run(form)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
from System.Windows.Forms import Application,Form
```

To:

```
from System.Windows.Forms import Application,Form,Label
```

Right now, the runtime doesn't know that "Label" is `System.Windows.Forms.Label`